# JavaFX TilePane doesn't wrap the text or showing Ellipsis String

Tags: java, layout, javafx

I am using a `TilePane` which contains a `GridPane` inside it and i have created it using `SceneBuilder` and `FXML`.The problem is that `TilePane` works very strange as the title is saying:

When the text is too big i have serious problems with the layouts cause the `TilePane` **isn't wrapping the text or showing Ellipsis String so when i resize the window all the layouts are failing into the app**.

Why this is happening with `TilePane` and is not working as expected inside a `BorderPane`?

---

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

---

Here is the fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<fx:root styleClass="smartController" type="StackPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="mainBorder" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: red;">
         <top>
            <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" graphicTextGap="0.0" text="I am The TilePane and i don't like wrapping the text!" wrapText="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <content>
                  <GridPane fx:id="topGrid" gridLinesVisible="true" hgap="5.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.85);;">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" percentWidth="70.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="40.0" percentWidth="15.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" percentWidth="15.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <TextField fx:id="pageField" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="65.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <tooltip>
                              <Tooltip text="current page" />
                           </tooltip>
                           <contextMenu>
                              <ContextMenu />
                           </contextMenu>
                        </TextField>
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </content>
            </TitledPane>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `TitledPane` has a `minWidth` based on the `text`. For it's parent to resize the node to a smaller size, you have to manually assign a value:

```xml
<TitledPane minWidth="0" fx:id="titledPane" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" graphicTextGap="0.0" text="I am The TilePane and i don't like wrapping the text!" wrapText="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
   ...
</TitledPane>
```

This can be set in the *Layout* section of the inspector of the `TitledPane` (`Min Width`).

As for actually wrapping the text:

The title part of the `TitledPane` is simply not large enough to allow multiple lines by default. You could change this using a css style sheet:

```css
#titledPane>.title {
    -fx-pref-height: 50; /* increase available area */
    -fx-alignment: top-center;
    -fx-padding: 4 4 4 30; /* increase left padding to align text */
}

#titledPane>.title>.arrow-button {
    -fx-translate-x: -20; /* move back arrow, which is also subject to the padding */
}
```

Comment: Hello Fabian.Thanks for the answer ,is there any way i can fix it from SceneBuilder , i can write directly to the code but i am curious.Is that the `minWidth` from the Layout drop menu at right ?

Comment: This doesn't work. Additionally this does not solve the height of the title when there is no need to wrap text (available space is enough).

Comment: Something like this can be achieved using this technique.
https://github.com/JPro-one/JPro-tickets/issues/147#issuecomment-1501767227

Answer (score 1):

The `TitledPane` -> `Title` *auto height with text-wrapping* can be achieved by using something like this codding:

```
private Node getView() {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    TitledPane titledPane2 = new TitledPane();
    titledPane2.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    titledPane2.setPrefWidth(400);
    titledPane2.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    titledPane2.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    Label lbl1 = new Label(
            "5 sample paragraphs for reading test on 1. Traveling in a D. T. C. Bus  2. Look Before You Leap 3. Rising Prices 4. ‘Simple Living, High Thinking’ 5. A Football Match");
    lbl1.setWrapText(true);
    lbl1.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    lbl1.setPadding(new Insets(0, 4.3, 0, 0));

    titledPane2.setGraphic(lbl1);

    Label lbl12 = new Label(
            "Delhi is a crowded city. There are very few rich people who travel by their own vehicles. The majority of the people cannot afford to hire a taxi or a three-wheeler. They have to depend on D.T.C. buses, which are the cheapest mode of conveyance.");
    lbl12.setWrapText(true);
    lbl12.setPadding(new Insets(4.3));

    titledPane2.setContent(lbl12);

    root.getChildren().addAll(titledPane2);

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Pane title = (Pane) titledPane2.lookup(".title");

        title.prefHeightProperty().bind(lbl1.heightProperty()
                .add(title.getInsets().getTop() + title.getInsets().getBottom()));
    });

    return root;
}
```

Output:

[image]

But it will be more better if it's fixed in official javafx repository.